# Where can I find the function definition in atomicity.h?

Tags: c++, stl, libstdc++

atomicity.h is part of c++ stl. In its source file, it declares two functions about atomic operation. Here is the whole source code. Where can I find the definition of these functions. I don't find it in stl source code.

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_ATOMICITY_H
#define _GLIBCXX_ATOMICITY_H    1
#include <bits/atomic_word.h>
namespace __gnu_cxx
{
  _Atomic_word 
  __attribute__ ((__unused__))
  __exchange_and_add(volatile _Atomic_word* __mem, int __val); 

  void
  __attribute__ ((__unused__))
  __atomic_add(volatile _Atomic_word* __mem, int __val); 
} // namespace __gnu_cxx
#endif
```

Comment: atomicity.h is not part of C++ STL...

Comment: Your include guards indicate that you are looking at the GCC implementation of the C++ standard library, **not** the STL. So, are you looking after an `atomicity.h` header in the STL, or are you looking for something else in the GCC C++ std lib? The C++ standard library does not define an `atomicity.h` header, but an implementation could well have one.

Answer (score 1):

They're defined by libstdc++, where exactly depends on your GCC installation, but for recent GCC releases it's easy to find out:

```
$ cat t.cc
#include <ext/atomicity.h>

int main()
{
  int i=0;
  __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(&i, 0);
}
$ g++ -g t.cc
$ gdb -quiet ./a.out
Reading symbols from /dev/shm/a.out...done.
(gdb) start 
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x8570: file t.cc, line 5.
Starting program: /dev/shm/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.cc:5
5     int i=0;
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.16-33.fc18.armv7hl libgcc-4.7.2-8.fc18.armv7hl libstdc++-4.7.2-8.fc18.armv7hl
(gdb) n
6     __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(&i, 0);
(gdb) step
__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add (__mem=0x7efff13c, __val=0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ext/atomicity.h:48
48    { return __atomic_fetch_add(__mem, __val, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL); }
(gdb)
```

GDB tells you where the definition is, in my case it's in `/usr/lib/gcc/armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/ext/atomicity.h` i.e. they're defined inline in `atomicity.h`

From the code you posted it looks like you're using GCC 4.1 (which is pretty old) in which case the functions are defined in the library, not in a header. The code is CPU-specific, so again it depends on your GCC installation.  The code can be found in the GCC sources, the i386 implementation is in the file [`libstdc++-v3/config/cpu/i386/atomicity.h`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_1-branch/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/config/cpu/i386/atomicity.h?view=markup) and the implementation for i486 and later is in [`libstdc++-v3/config/cpu/i486/atomicity.h`](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_1-branch/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/config/cpu/i486/atomicity.h?view=markup)

Comment: Are the functions available on ARM dev-boards with GCC 4.9 installed? I'm testing with Clang 3.5.0, and it is failing to link with error, *`In function __gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add(int volatile*, int):
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/ext/atomicity.h:49: undefined reference to __atomic_fetch_add_4`*.

Comment: @jww that's s completely separate question. The function is obviously available, because you're calling it. The error you're getting is from the definition of that function. If the `__atomic` built-ins result in a call to an external function then you need to link to `libatomic`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll file a Clang bug report. We don't call `__exchange_and_add`. I suspect Clang is calling it for C++11's Dynamic Initialization and Destruction with Concurrency.

Comment: @jww I very much doubt Clang is automatically generating calls to that function. It will be called by something else in libstdc++.

Answer (score 0):

`<atomicity.h>` is part of the Linux libraries.  I think it gets bundled into libc.  It is not part of the STL or any C++ standard.  It is a Linux specific header.

That being said, `__exchange_and_add` may not be a function at all.  There are several behaviors that GCC supports internally, and atomic operations tend to be in that group.

Comment: No, they're functions defined by libstdc++

Comment: To expand on that, it's not part of the STL or the C++ standard, but is an implementation detail of libstdc++. It is a normal function, but will use GCC's built-in atomic operations if available.